# scaling elements to fit browser window

Tags: css, layout, cross-browser, positioning, vimeo

The page in question is this: http://amytdatta.com/ironic-bironic (password: tyma) - it's a pre-release page for a new album I worked on, sorry!

I'd like to have the video and the text nav below scale and center to the browser window without the need for a scrollbar. I've tried all kinds of approaches using `min height` / `max height` but just can't seem to get the intended result. I'm guessing that I don't know which elements to target and how to target them.

Any advice for a good solid approach would be really appreciated. Also, since i'm using Virb I can only do overrides to the CSS, so I can't delete lines.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Without actually seeing your website since it's password protected I would suggest something along the lines of the folllowing:

You set a wrapper around your elements, in your case the nav and the video. And then set the CSS for the video and nav to have an auto margin. Which should center it both horizontally and verically. You might want to add a wrapper for the 2 components to keep them nicely stacked together and then put an auto margin on that wrapper, but the below should already work.

Html:

```
       <div id="container">
         <div id="nav"><!-- nav here --></div>
         <div id="video"><!--video here--></div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

#video{
  margin:auto;
}

#nav {
  margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: The password is "tyma". Do you think you could have a look? Since i'm using virb all the HTML and CSS is pre-coded and I can only modify existing code. Really appreciate your time! Thanks.

Comment: I can have a look at it a bit later if that's ok?

Comment: Oh of course, whenever is convenient for you. I am really very grateful for your time!

Comment: Sorry not yet, been really busy will do it today

Comment: No worries! Appreciate it!